# How do I use percentages with MotionValues in Framer Motion?

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion

Using Framer Motion's `useTransform` I want to change the width of an element using a `MotionValue` that is a percent (eg. `75%`) rather than in pixels.

The default assumes pixels:

```
<motion.div className="dynamic-element" style={{ width: w }}>
```

I want something like the following:

```
<motion.div className="dynamic-element" style={{ width:`${w}%` }}>
```

Which obviously doesn't work.

How can I specify that my `MotionValue` is a percentage and not pixel-based?

Alternatively, I can use `filter: scale()` but that results in the contents being blurry (and yes I've looked into how to fix that, but haven't had any success).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this :

```
useTransform(w, (value) => `${value}%`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use variants?

E.g.:

```
<motion.div
  variants={{
    a: {width: '20%'},
    b: {width: '50%'}
  }}
  animate={variant}
/>
```

See this [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animate-width-percent-opehw?file=/src/App.tsx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentages as the output value.

```
const width = useTransform(w, [0, someOtherNumberYouPick], ['0%', '100%'])
...
<motion.div className="dynamic-element" style={{ width }}>
```

Comment: It does not work. we get width:0% and it does not change.